# What is the best way to schedule a task using netlify, heroky or any other service?

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, mern, netlify

I am creating a service that will allow users to schedule social media posts. Currently, I am thinking about using the cron-job API to create cron jobs that will call netlify functions.

Is this the correct way to implement this feature?

Comment: Please review what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is both (a) too broad and (b) too opinion-based to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netlify launched a feature for scheduling jobs/tasks similar to corn job. You can checkout their document for more detail and implementation.
https://github.com/netlify/labs/blob/main/features/scheduled-functions/documentation/README.md
Netlify Blog: https://www.netlify.com/blog/quirrel-joins-netlify-and-scheduled-functions-launches-in-beta

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).